# How do I select rows with certain value, if I do not know what column this value belongs to?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

For instance, here is the dataframe

```
1     2
high  wide
high  thin
short wide
short thin
```

I want to select all the rows that contain value 'wide'. And let's suppose that I do not know, what column contains such values.

This is just a simplified example. I need it in order to iterate through the unique table values, that are organized into an array.

```py
for uv in uniqueValues:
    valueObjects = """select all the rows that contain uv"""
```

Is there a way to do this without determining a column for every value?
I mean, this could work

```py
for uv in uniqueValues:
    for col in table.columns:
        colValues = table[col].unique()
        if uv in colValues:
            valueObjects = table[table[col] == uv]
            break
```

But I hope there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.eq('wide').any(axis=1)]
#alternative
#df = df[(df == 'wide').any(axis=1)]
print (df)
       1     2
0   high  wide
2  short  wide
```

**Detail**:

First compare all values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) or `==` for boolean `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.eq('wide'))
       1      2
0  False   True
1  False  False
2  False   True
3  False  False
```

Then test it at least one `True` per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print(df.eq('wide').any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```